# Using 2 RAM sticks of different brand and run in dual channel

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I have a 2018 HP pre-built PC that has 2 RAM slots, both used. 1 slot has a 8GB or brand SK Hynix thats DDR4-2667, with CAS of 19-19-19-43 according to Cpu-Z.

The second stick is 4 GB of brand Micron, DDR4-2667 again, with CAS 19-19-19-43(according to CPU-Z again). I could not find the exact specifications from the manufacturer from both sticks so this is according to CPU-Z software

According to the HP website for my specific PC model (HP 690-0039), the motherboard''Supports up to PC4-21300 (DDR4 2666) UDIMM'' and the current installed ram are also PC4-21300 (DDR4 2666).

The RAM still run at dual channel even if they are from 2 different brand

My question is, since both sticks are already not from the same brand, could I replace the 4GB stick with a 8GB one, also at 2666mhz and 19-19-19-43 CAS timing? Will they still run in dual-channel? What if I put a stick that has a lower CAS timing (ex: 16-16-16-39) and that is PC4-19200 instead of PC4-21300? would that still work in dual channel with a different CAS and Mhz?

Thank you

Comment: With your replacement you will not get full dual-channel speed but the overlap on the two DIMMs will work as dual channel. Take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/912283/can-mixing-ram-memory-size-on-its-own-reduce-dual-channel-performance/912298) post.

Comment: @doneal24 thank you for your reply. However does that mean since the 2 current ram sticks are different brand and size but same speedare working as overlap dual channel? and since my replacement would be same size (8GB) as the first stick, and with same speed and mhz, would they work as dual channel then? what if I use the one with lower CAS and PC4-19200 instead of PC4-21300(first stick is PC4-21300)?